# Why is ethanol written as C2H5OH not C2H6O?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, notation

This is balanced equation of fermentation of glucose:

$$\ce{C6H12O6(aq) -> 2C2H5OH(aq) + 2CO2(g)}$$

I know that the result of glucose fermentation is ethanol ($\ce{C2H6O}$). What represented in the aforementioned equation is slightly different. I would like to know what $\ce{C2H5OH}$ is?

What is the OH functional group doing here? Does it make ethanol acidic? Does it mean that ethanol is diluted with water?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is better to write $\ce{C_2H_6O}$ as $\ce{C_2H_5OH}$, because there is more than one compound with the same overall formula, and emphasising the *hydroxyl group* $\ce{-OH}$, which is what characterizes an *alcohol* makes it *ethanol* and nothing else.  So when you ask, "What is OH functional group doing here", it is exactly that the product is an alcohol, characterized by a hydroxyl group. And yes, alcohols *are* acidic in the right situations, given that their hydroxyl groups do produce acidic hydrogen ions, and yes, that is why it's so soluble in water.

Answer (score 1):

I confused compound formula with the actual formula of ethanol. Compound formula is $\ce{C2H6O}$. But the actual molecular structure is $\ce{CH3CH2OH}$. The oxygen is attached to hydrogen which it in turn is attached to Carbon.